# VBA Excel sorting on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have an Excel table, where I'd like that all rows (except the header row) in Sheet "CR" that have a value in it (excluding formulas if possible (column A contains formulas)) are sorted first by column B (name = TEAM), then C (name = BUILDING) and finally D (name = DATE_MAJ) before the file is saved.

I'm an absolute noob with VBA, so I'm trying out stuff that I find left and right on the fora and modify it to my needs. From searching around, I tried this code in the Excel VBA Object 'Workbook', but it gives an error:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Setup column names
Col1name = "SECTION"
Col2name = "BATIMENT"
Col3name = "DATE_MAJ"

'Find cols
For Each cell In Range("A1:" & Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Address)
    If cell.Value = Col1name Then
        Col1 = cell.Column
    End If
    If cell.Value = Col2name Then
        Col2 = cell.Column
    End If
    If cell.Value = Col3name Then
        Col3 = cell.Column
    End If

Next

'Below two line:- if they are blank e.g. column not found it will error so a small bit of error handling 
If Col1 = "" Then Exit Sub
If Col2 = "" Then Exit Sub
If Col3 = "" Then Exit Sub

'Find last row - dynamic part
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

'Convert col numer to name
Col1 = Split(Cells(1, Col1).Address(True, False), "$")
Col2 = Split(Cells(1, Col2).Address(True, False), "$")
Col3 = Split(Cells(1, Col3).Address(True, False), "$")

'Sort
With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Col1(0) & "2:" & Col1(0) & lastrow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Col2(0) & "2:" & Col2(0) & lastrow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(Col3(0) & "2:" & Col3(0) & lastrow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .SetRange Range("A1:K" & lastrow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

I'd be grateful for any help in getting the code right. Below is a link to the Excel file (I took out the above code as it didn't work).

[Dropbox link to Excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gx5y2onh3gg54d5/CR%20projet2-test.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: What error do you experience? What line is throwing it? Furthermore your linked example doesn't have any columns header named after neither "BATIMENT" nor "DATE_MAJ"

Comment: The column names of columns C and D are "BATIMENT" and "DATE_MAJ" ; their headers are indeed "BUILDING" and "DATE UPDATE". Does that matter?

Comment: The error I'm getting is 'Compile error: variable not defined' and 'Col1name' is selected in the VBA code.

Comment: If your searching for a name (say "BATIMENT") in a range that doesn't have it (since there's a "BUILDING" somewhere), then you won't find it! As for the error: do you have an `Option Explicit` statement at the top of your Module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have three sorting columns you may want to use [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) method of `Range` object, instead of the namesake method of `Worksheet` object

Furthermore assuming columns headers as per linked excel files you could try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim col1 As Range, col2 As Range, col3 As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Setup column names
    Const col1Name As String = "SECTION"
    Const col2Name As String = "BUILDING" '"BATIMENT"
    Const col3Name As String = "DATE UPDATE" '"DATE_MAJ"

    With Worksheets("CR") '<--| reference your worksheet
        'Find last row - dynamic part
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row ' <--|find its column "A" last not empty row index
        'Find cols
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '<--|reference its row 1 cells from column 1 to last not empty one and search for sorting columns whose header matches above set column names
            If Not TryGetColumnIndex(.Cells, col1Name, col1) Then Exit Sub '<--| if 1st sorting column not found then exit sub
            If Not TryGetColumnIndex(.Cells, col2Name, col2) Then Exit Sub '<--| if 2nd sorting column not found then exit sub
            If Not TryGetColumnIndex(.Cells, col3Name, col3) Then Exit Sub '<--| if 3rd sorting column not found then exit sub
            .Resize(lastRow).Sort _
                            key1:=col1, order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                            key2:=col2, order2:=xlAscending, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
                            key3:=col3, order3:=xlAscending, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal, _
                            Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, SortMethod:=xlPinYin
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function TryGetColumnIndex(rng As Range, colName As String, col As Range) As Boolean
    Set col = rng.Find(What:=colName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    TryGetColumnIndex = Not col Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but that code gives the following: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. When clicking 'debug', the following line is highlighted: lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).rowrow ' <--|find its column "A" last not empty row index

Comment: I pasted the code in the object 'ThisWorkbook'. I assume that's right?

Comment: @Antoon, did you get through it?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! There was still one small typo in the line following '.Resize(lastRow).Sort _' : changed col2 to col1 and now it works like a charm!

Comment: @Anton, if you want to `Autofit` rows after sorting, add `.Resize(lastRow).Rows.AutoFit` right after the `.Resize(lastRow).Sort ...` statement