# VBA for sorting in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a code that sorts the entries i put from a userform.

In column C, I have the project name and in column D i have the position. The code currently sorts based off of Column C in the worksheet.

The issue I am having is that i need it to Sort based off of column C first and then Column B. Currently the code Finds entries matching in column C and just adds to the bottom row.

```
Sub Sortit()
    With Sheet1
        .Range("B5:W10000").Sort Key1:=.Range("C3"), Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's in the first 4 rows, and why isn't the key one of the headings? Wait, there's no header?? Can a header be added?

Comment: The Column Headers are in C4-K4, First 3 rows are empty

Comment: It's not clear why your range starts at `B5` then. Have you tried `.Range("B4:K10000").Sort Key1:=.Range("C4"), Header:=xlYes`? Also I'd warmly recommend removing the empty lines and converting your range to a table/`ListObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sub works for me to sort a worksheet by two columns- first by A and then by B.  I believe that is answering your question although it is a little unclear.

```
Sub sort()
 Range("A1:C7").Select
    Selection.sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B1") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Example of final state-

```
A   B   C
blj asd b
blj er  d
blj fd  c
dflkj   6   e
ldkfj   7   a
ldkfj   7   f
```

Comment: Philip the code works great! the only issue is that after the entry from the userform is in the worksheet and sorted, the whole worksheet is selected. An easy fix

Answer (score 0):

I would mark this question as a duplicate but I don't have the needed rep points. You should find your answer in [VBA Excel sorting on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40562830/vba-excel-sorting-on-multiple-columns) 
should be something like...

```
.Sort_                                                                            key1:=col1,order1:=xlAscending,DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
 key2:=col2, order2:=xlAscending, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
 key3:=col3, order3:=xlAscending, DataOption3:=xlSortNormal, _
```